# Doubt about whether a set is Borel or not and whether a collection of sets is a subbasis for some topology.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am self studying measure theory from Walter Rudin Real and Complex Analysis and I was thinking about some additional question in one of the exercise problem which is problem 11 of chapter 1 given on page 32 .

This is  that particular exercise of [Rudin's book][1].﻿ ﻿
 Theorem 1.41. Let $\{E_k\}$ be a sequence of measurable sets in $(X,\eta,\mu)$ ($\eta$ is $\sigma$ algebra, $\mu$ is a positive measure),such that ﻿ $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k)<\infty. \tag{1}$$﻿ ﻿ Then almost all $x\in X$ lie in at most finitely of sets $E_k$.﻿

I completely understand the above theorem.

Then the above mentioned exercise ( based on above mentioned theoram)
Exercise: Show that ﻿ $$A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}{E_k} \tag{2}$$﻿ ﻿ ﻿ in Theorem 1.41, and hence prove the theorem without any reference to integration.

I proved this exercise.

But my questions are ----> 1. Is the above mentioned set A,  a Borel Set ?

2. Is { $ E_k $ a subbasis for topology on X ?   If yes then what is that topology?

Can somebody please help  .

Comment: I think this is pure measure theory without reference to anything topological, so it's not about Borel sets, sub basis, ...

Comment: @zhw.  I have removed tags general topology and borel sets